# Parse phone number with regular expression and replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some phone number with country code (e.g. `var number = +12013334444`), which I should parse by specific way (e.g. 1 2013334444). Also I save the country code without '+' in variable (e.g. `countryCode === 1 // true`). I think will be nice to parse it with a help of regular expression and replace function. Something like this:

```
  number.replace(/(countryCode)(/[0-9]/gi)/, '$1 $2');
```

But it's not working for me. Is there any elegant way to parse number without using indexOf() and substr()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var number = "+12013334444";
var countryCode = "1";

var formattedValue = number.split( "+" + countryCode ).join( "+" + countryCode + " " );
alert( formattedValue );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var numbers = [
  '+12013334444',
  '+1 2013334444'
];
var output = numbers.map(function(number) {
  return number.replace(/(\+[0-9])(?! )/, '$1 ');
}).join('\n');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```